# Underline entire line in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

is there a way to underline entire line of code in algorithm2e? Including keywords like for each etc.

Comment: This seems very related to another recent question of yours: [Underline line numbers in algorithm2e](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241963) I'd suggest adding this information and a minimal working example at that question.